# Replication/repeated measures problem

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have some data with a repeated measures problem. As an example of my problem, let's imagine you are interested in how a person's weight influences their blood pressure. However, there is a problem in the study because each person's blood pressure and weight was measured on twice.

Normally with repeated measurements like this I would use a mixed model with a random intercept of subject. However, unlike with those studies I am not necessarily interested in how a person's blood pressure and weight are related over time or between the two measurements, but also how blood pressure and weight are related between my different subjects.

You could even imagine a case where the two relationships would be opposite one-another. For instance, if the second machine overestimated blood pressure and underestimated weight compared to the first machine, then between subjects there would be a positive relationship between blood pressure and weight but within subjects there would be a negative relationship.

How can I write two different models to test for these two different research questions/hypotheses?

Q1: How is blood pressure related to weight between subjects?
Q2: How is blood pressure to weight within subjects?

Also, I am aware that for Q1 I could average the two measurements together for each participant, but it seems this would throw out information about the variability of the measurements and lesson statistical power.I would prefer to account for the lack of independence within the model.

To illustrate, for Q1 I am interested in the overall trend, and would expect a positive slope as I do not care about trends within individuals, but just want to control for the lack of independence.

[image]

And for Q2 I would expect a negative slope, as I would be interested in the trend within each individual.

[image]

Comment: you could do within-subject centering, e.g. see van de Pol and Wright, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.468.8761&rep=rep1&type=pdf